# Meteor - node simple schema validate data to match schema

Tags: rest, meteor, simple-schema

I want to change my `Rest-API` validation to `node simple schema` for schema definition and `collection2@core` for schema validation.

I want to use the `Person schema` to validate the `data` provided by the users.

```
Schemas = {};
Schemas.Person = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: "Person's Name",
        unique: true,
        max: 200
    },
    surname: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        label: "person's surname"
    },
};

validData = API.utility.validate(data, Schemas.Person });

API: {
  utility: {
    validate: function(data, schema) {
      return "The SimpleSchema Validation";
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This case is described in the [simpl-schema documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simpl-schema#validate-an-object-and-get-the-errors)

With your schema definition you can just do:

```
Schemas.person.validate(data);
```

If right after that you want to look at the result or the errors:

```
Schemas.person.isValid();
Schemas.person.validationErrors();
```